# Encoding troubles with Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

How can I make String `Стек` look like `%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA`? Which encoding is it? How can I do it with Java? I thought it's `UTF-8`:

```
 String myString = "Стек";
 byte text[] = myString.getBytes();
 String value = new String(text, "UTF-8");
 System.out.println(value);
```

But no, I've got `Стек` in output.

Comment: Looks like URL encoding to me. Note that UTF-8 is a text->binary conversion. You're looking for a text->text conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not UTF-8, it's URL-like encoding, and you can get it using the `URLEncoder` class:

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode("Стек");
System.out.println(encoded);
```

Result:

```
%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA
```

[IDEOne working example](http://ideone.com/KD0KzG)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) class to convert a `String` to percent encoding:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("Стек", "utf-8"));
```

You'll also need to catch `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Answer (score 2):

The text that you've shown is [Percent encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) or URL encoded.

You can use [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) for converting it to the desired format:

```
String value = URLEncoder.encode("Стек", "ISO-8859-1");
```